# Understanding Polymorphic Associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I have a parent model called Quote. which has an attribute called final_quote and has a child model called QuoteBoms, which has attributes called quote_final_quote and quantity and total_quote (=quote_final_quote * quantity)

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quote_boms, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote_boms, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

class QuoteBom < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :quote
    has_many :quotes
end
```

Now in the nested model, I am selecting the quote with the association "belongs_to :quote" but has_many :quotes does not work as I have only one `quote_id` column (I suppose this is the problem). I see that i need to define a third class as quotebom_quote_id but cannot figure out how exactly!

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what are you trying to do with it? explain properly

Comment: try using `has_and_belongs_to_many :quotes` in `QuoteBom` Model instead of that two lines.

Comment: I am bulding an app where user can make quotes for a given item. A quote can belong to another quote though the nested model, and in multiple quantities.

Comment: @AmolUdage thank you! I will try this and update!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images, :as => :imageable
end
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images, :as => :imageable
end
```

This is how we have made a single **Image** model and it is accessed by one or more than one model

Please refer this
[Link](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Polymorphic-association/5122/)

Comment: Thanks for your help.. apreciated very much, what i needed was another foriegn id column in the quotebom

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you wish to create a database structure containing the models Quote and QuoteBom where a Quote has many QuoteBom and QuoteBom belongs to many Quotes.

That being the case, you will want to use a [has_and_belongs_to_many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

This will require adding to your models

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :quote_boms
end

class QuoteBom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :quotes
end
```

...and the following migration (assuming Quote and QuoteBom already exist)

```
class CreateQuotesAndQuoteBoms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quote_quote_boms, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :quote, index: true
      t.belongs_to :quote_bom, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

By having the associations above in the model and this table in your database, rails will automagically handle the associations between quote and quote_doms. As a result, you will also be able to access quote_dom.quotes which you said you weren't able to do in your question.

This is **NOT** a polymorphic association. A polymorphic association allows a model to belong to more than one type of other model in a single association.

Comment: @hypem, thanks for your answer. I will try this ASAP.

Comment: Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many.. given that I have extra attributes in the QuoteBom would you suggest to use has_many :through instead of has_and_belongs_to_many?

Comment: Yes, if the relationship requires attributes, callbacks or validations you should use a has many through relationship instead.

Comment: Hello hypem, thanks for your remark again. I created these tables, however still have problems I want to have quote_boms as nested_attributes model within quotes. Your guidance will be invaluable!

Comment: Hey hypem, dont bother.. i have found a solution. My problem was not this at all.. I just needed another foreign id column in QuoteBom refering Quote. All set.  Thanks for your help.. apreciated very much